# how can I get request method with PHP (application/json)

Tags: php

I am new with php,

I want to know,

how can I get request method whitch content type is application/json in PHP

except  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];`

have other to get request method?

anyone ideas?

thanks a lot !

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, this has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is used for getting request method, which could be `GET`, `HEAD`, `POST`, `PUT`.

Content-type application/json is the type of `response`. For example, your PHP server can get a POST request, and respond a JSON data using `application/json` headers.

Comment: except $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] , have other to get request method?

Comment: No, and request method and content-type of the previous file are different things.

Answer (score 0):

In headers HTTP sent is info about Content-Type. Content-Type information about type of data. Best way to validate header Content-Type in PHP:

```
<?php
    $json = false;
    $h = get_headers('http://127.0.0.1', 1);
    if(isset($h['Content-Type']) and $h['Content-Type']=='application/json') {
        $json = true;                       
    }
?>
```

Popular types of Content-type: text/html, text/plain, application/json, application/javascript, application/xml

Answer (score 0):

Client Requests doesnt have content type. Clients have "Accept-Type" please check [Accept headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1)

and you can handle it by `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']` in php.